# I cannot create a new object using javassist if I try to override a method

Tags: java, methods, overriding, code-injection, javassist

I'm injecting a new method in a class using CtNewMethod.make and everything seems to be working fine, if the object I use in the method is not modified:
I made a custom method to get the object:

```
public String getObj() {
   return "new bgr()";
}
```

But, if I try to override a method like this:

```
public String getObj() {
return "new bgr() " +
            "{" +
                "public void a(int x, int y, float pt) {" +
                    "super.a(x, y, pt);" +
                "}" +
            "}";
}
```

It gives me an error:
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] ) is missing

I tried everything even with the ")" char but nothing seems to work

Thanks in advance

PS: the method and the class do exist, they just have random names due to the jar being obfuscated

Answer (score 0):

As per javassist documentation "Inner classes or anonymous classes are not supported": https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#limit

Your only options is to generate a new class(lets call it "bgrExt") that extends "bgr" and has the method `bgr::a` overridden. Then in your code you instantiate as `new bgrExt()`.

Comment: Well, that explains it. Though I don't really know how you should create an extended one, should I make it as a new CtClass?

Comment: Yes, something along the lines of: `ClassPool cp =...; CtClass cc = cp.makeClass("bgrExt"); cc.setSuperclass(cp.get("bgr"));`

Comment: I was succesful! Thanks a lot for the help :)